# Angular Material beforeClosed and afterAllClosed dos not exists on matDialog

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to implement matDialog on my view but a got an error triying to use beforeClosed, it says is not an function but also it doesn't exist on matDialog. The same for afterAllClosed.

Can enyone help me?

```
Dialog:MatDialog;
constructor( Dialog:MatDialog ){ this.Dialog = Dialog; }

const DialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
DialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
DialogConfig.data = Provider;
this.Dialog.open(DialogComponent, DialogConfig);
this.Dialog.beforeClosed().subscribe(result => {
    console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
})
```

Property 'beforeClosed' does not exist on type 'MatDialog'

ERROR TypeError: this.Dialog.beforeClosed is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i found the solution, i need to get the instance of the dialog im opening.

```
let CurrentDialog = this.Dialog.open(ProviderEditorComponent, DialogConfig);
CurrentDialog.beforeClosed().subscribe(result => {
  console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
});
```